# React Redux pass props to other component enhancer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I have 2 components, `ReviewList` and `Review`. `ReviewList` has a list of components `Review` and for each component `Review` has a property **review**.

I want to put some logic work on the component so I want to create an *enhancer* (*Review.enhancer.js*) to do that type of work (I want the component `Review` to be a dummy component).

I'm using **react-redux** and on my `Review.enhancer` I am using connect method to get the prop ({review}) but I got nothing. I'm noob in react and redux.

Comment: Can you show Review.enhancer.js

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't necessarily need the `connect` function if you already provide the data by passing it as a prop to the enhancer. In this case you could also use the `recompose` library to apply logic to the data. However, in most cases you still need to dispatch actions, so the `connect` function from `react-redux` would still be required.

When props are passed to a component that is wrapped by a `connect` function, they will not be automatically passed down. In order to make these props accessible to the wrapped component, you need to map them from the second argument in the `mapStateToProps` function.

**Review.enhancer.js**

```
const mapStateToProps =  (state, ownProps) => {
    return { 
        review: ownProps.review,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Review);
```

Now only the review prop is being passed down to the wrapped component. However, you should try to avoid doing this, because it couples the enhancer to the container component.

> Note that if you want to pass all the props to the wrapped 
>      component, you can omit the parentheses from the arrow 
>      function and use an implicit return.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification, it worked like a charm